# react-redux-starter-kit npm run dev crashes

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am new to React/Redux and I am using the react-redux-starter-kit boilerplate to delve into it. `npm run dev` was working fine, but now it is crashing with this error:

> express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0 dev /Users/unomas/Documents/web/suited-template
>   webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at net.js:1395:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0 dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the express-react-redux-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs express-react-redux-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls express-react-redux-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/unomas/Documents/web/suited-template/npm-debug.log
```

npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.9
3 info using node@v4.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info predev express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0
6 info dev express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0 Failed to exec dev script
9 verbose stack Error: express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0
11 verbose cwd /Users/unomas/Documents/web/suited-template
12 error Darwin 14.5.0
13 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
14 error node v4.5.0
15 error npm  v2.15.9
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the express-react-redux-starter@1.0.0 dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the express-react-redux-starter package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs express-react-redux-starter
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls express-react-redux-starter
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Not sure if anyone is familiar with this boilerplate or error. Please let me know of any ways to resolve. Thanks

Comment: did you changed anything in webpack config file? or u just running source code? add referance of source from where are you refering from

Comment: Made no changes to the webpack config file nor any other config settings. Source is here: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

Comment: whats ur npm version?

Comment: It's version 2.15.9

Comment: i think you should update npm first and then build the process again

Comment: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3000` looks like it is already running somewhere

Comment: just write to console `killall node` and try it again..

Comment: hm... none of the above seem to work. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another server already running at localhost:3000. Try hitting it in your browser to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you were tired of handling webpack configuration, please give [Chalet Starter App](https://github.com/chungchiehlun/chalet-starter-app) a try.
It applied command like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to bootstrap your app and the folder structure was based on [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit). Please see the [Quick Overview](https://github.com/chungchiehlun/chalet-starter-app#quick-overview) for more detail. Welcome to open an issue if you had another question.

Comment: Perhaps you should actually describe how your project solves OPs issue. I don't immediately see the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I thought OPs' issue was hard to configure webpack with react-redux-starter-kit or express-react-redux-starter. Accordingly, using command line might reduce the effort and OP could get the hang of the kit soon.